# Automatically uninstall unused applications in SCCM 2012

Tags: powershell, sccm

1. Is there a way to automatically uninstall unused applications in SCCM 2012?

I thought of a PowerShell script. Which lists the local installed Applications and compares to the group assigned by the user in the AD. If there is an installed application without group assignment, the application should be uninstalled.

1. I have had very little to do with PowerShell and want to ask if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Don't ask yes/no questions unless you want the answer to be yes or no (it's "yes", BTW). Also, don't expect people here to do your work for you. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have sofware usage metering data - corresponding feature should be enabled & configured in SCCM, probably some usage statistics can be gathered on a client side by enabling some logging/metering built into client OS (not sure about latter at the moment).
Then having software usage metering data you may establish threshold suitable for you (e.g. software is unused if it was never run at all, newer run for certain period of time etc.) and select and run uninstall of this sofware by running script against all your machines/users.
This is just an outline of how it possibly could be done.

Further reading (describe exactly asking about with use of Orchestrator Runbook Automation and ability to opt out from assigned uninstall for user):

1) [Software Metering Deep Dive and Automation Part 1: Use It Or Lose It - The Basics](http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilp/archive/2012/11/27/software-metering-deep-dive-and-automation-part-1-use-it-or-lose-it-the-basics.aspx)

2) [Software Metering Deep Dive and Automation Part 2: Use It Or Lose It - The Collections](http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilp/archive/2012/11/29/software-metering-deep-dive-and-automation-part-2-use-it-or-lose-it-the-collections.aspx)

3) [Software Metering Deep Dive and Automation Part 3: Use It Or Lose It - The Orchestrator Runbook Automation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilp/archive/2013/01/02/software-metering-deep-dive-and-automation-part-3-use-it-or-lose-it-the-orchestrator-runbook-automation.aspx)

By the way there is a little pitfall here: software metering just track runs of app & probably time it has been running for, but this in not always equals to real application usage (it may be simple configured to autostart but ignored by user)